# force NCKS to try to append when used in batch script

Tags: netcdf, nco

I want to use ncks in a batch script to select a variable an append it to a file:

```
ncks  -v ${var} $infile $outfile
```

But interactively it asks me whether I want to exit, overwrite or append.

On the help page of the command there is this tip:

"Some users may wish to avoid interactive ncks queries about whether to overwrite existing data. For example, batch scripts will fail if ncks does not receive responses to its queries. Options -O and -A are available to force overwriting existing files and variables, respectively."

but I don't want to overwrite, I wish to append, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
ncks -A -v ${var} $infile $outfile
```

For me it appended selected variable `$var` to the `$outfile` without the prompt.

Comment: duh, why didn't I think of that?  Forcing overwrite of variables assumes append for file... Thanks!